# CXProviderDelegate Methods not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, callkit

My goal is to open my `CallViewController` after the user answers the call. I've read some excerpts here on SO that it can be done using:

```
- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performAnswerCallAction:(CXAnswerCallAction *)action {
    NSLog(@"performAnswerCallAction");
}

- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performStartCallAction:(CXStartCallAction *)action {
     NSLog(@"performStartCallAction");
}
```

The code above is inside AppDelegate.

However, using NSLogs, these methods aren't triggered at all. I can't seem to find any tutorials on implementing using `Objective-C` that is easy to understand from a beginner's POV. I would appreciate any insights, thanks!

Comment: You are making the call or receiving the call?

Comment: receiving the call @RJVKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, did you set the delegate of `CXProvider`?

```
let provider = CXProvider(configuration: your_call_kit_config)
provider.setDelegate(self, queue: nil) // 'nil' means it will run on main queue
```

Also, have the `AppDelegate.swift` file conform to `CXProviderDelegate`

`provider:performAnswerCallAction:` gets called when user taps on 'Answer' button on the incoming call screen provided by the system. (Apple documentation [**HERE**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxproviderdelegate/1648270-provider?language=objc)).

`provider:performStartCallAction:` gets called after successful request to `CXCallController` to perform a `CXStartCallAction` (Apple documentation [**HERE**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxproviderdelegate/1648260-provider?language=objc)).

**EDIT**: For Objective-C

Ok here is the Objective-C snippet, for example, in the `AppDelegate`. First, you need to make `AppDelegate` conform to the `CXProviderDelegate`, Like so:

```
@interface AppDelegate () <CXProviderDelegate>
```

Then, add a property for `CXProvider` and `CXCallController`, like so:

```
@interface AppDelegate () <CXProviderDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, nonnull, strong) CXProvider *provider;
@property (nonatomic, nonnull, strong) CXCallController *callController;

@end
```

In the AppDelegate's function **application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:**, initialize `CXProvider` object with the call configuration, like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Setup CallKit
    CXProviderConfiguration *providerConfiguration = [[CXProviderConfiguration alloc] initWithLocalizedName:@"MyApp"];
    providerConfiguration.supportsVideo = YES;
    providerConfiguration.includesCallsInRecents = YES;
    self.provider = [[CXProvider alloc] initWithConfiguration: providerConfiguration];

    // Since `AppDelegate` conforms to `CXProviderDelegate`, set it to the provider object
    // Setting 'nil' to `queue` argument means, that the methods will be executed on main thread.
    // Optionally, you can assign private serial queue to handle `CXProvider` method responses
    [self.provider setDelegate:self queue:nil];

    // Initialize `CallController`
    self.callController = [[CXCallController alloc] init];

    return YES;
```

}

And on the bottom of **AppDelegate.m** file, implement `CXProviderDelegate` methods:

```
#pragma mark: - CXProvider delegate methods

- (void)providerDidReset:(CXProvider *)provider {
    // Drop all calls here (if there are pending)
}

/*!
 This method gets called when user presses on 'Accept' button on the incoming call screen provided by the system.
 Here you should configure `AVAudioSession` for VoIP calls and handle logic for answering the call.
 */
- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performAnswerCallAction:(CXAnswerCallAction *)action {
    // Put your answering logic here
    // Note: It is important to fulfill the action inside the scope of it's function, or to fail, depending if error occured during answering
    [action fulfill];
}

/*!
 This method gets called when CXCallController object finishes the CXStartCallAction request. You need to request
 start call action to the CXCallController instance, when starting an outgoing VoIP call. After successful transaction,
 the provider will respond with this delegate method. Here you should also configure `AVAudioSession` for VoIP calls.
 */
- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performStartCallAction:(CXStartCallAction *)action {
    // Put your outgoing call action here
    // Note: It is important to fulfill the action inside the scope of it's function, or to fail, depending if error occured during starting a call
    [action fulfill];
}
```

To start an outgoing VoIP call, you need to request the transaction with the action to the CXCallController instance, like so:

```
#pragma mark - Call Controller requests

- (void)startOutgoingVoIPCallWithNumber:(NSString *)number {
    NSUUID *callUUID = [NSUUID UUID]; // Here you create or assign UUID of call.
    CXHandle *callHandle = [[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:CXHandleTypePhoneNumber value:number];
    CXStartCallAction *startCallAction = [[CXStartCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:callUUID handle:callHandle];
startCallAction.video = YES; // Yes or no is call is video or audio.

    CXTransaction *startCallTransaction = [[CXTransaction alloc] initWithAction:startCallAction];

    [self.callController requestTransaction:startCallTransaction completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            // Handle start call error here
            // Ususally, error occurs if the system cannot handle the new outgoing call, since there are others pending
        }
        // If there is no error, CXProvider will respond with `provider:performStartCallAction:` method.
    }];
}
```

To display system call screen

```
#pragma mark - Report New incoming call

/*!
 You need to call this function each time you receive a new incoming call, usually right from the VoIP push notification.
 */
- (void)reportNewIncomingCallWithNumber:(NSString *)number {
    NSUUID *callUUID = [NSUUID UUID]; // Call UUID, you should have this in some Call object, not generating the new here
    CXHandle *callHandle = [[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:CXHandleTypePhoneNumber value:number];
    CXCallUpdate *callInfo = [[CXCallUpdate alloc] init];
    callInfo.remoteHandle = callHandle;
    [self.provider reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:[NSUUID UUID] update:callInfo completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            // Handle error here
        }
        // If there is no error, system will display incoming call screen and when user taps on 'Answer',
        // `CXProvider` will respond with `provider:performAnswerCallAction:`
    }];
}
```

Comment: could you please give an example of this using ObjC? thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer with the Objective-C snippet.

Comment: Miki, I've tried doing the snippet you have provided. AppDelegate is conforming to `CXProviderDelegate`, also implemented its delegate methods, but my logs on `performAnswerCallAction` still cant be shown. Do you have idea?

Comment: also, does 'initWithLocalizedName:@"MyApp"' string matters? Or any string will work?

Comment: Well, i think you need to provide localized name for the CallKit. Wether you init CXProviderConfiguration with localized name, or provide it later, I still think it is required. The name that you provide will be displayed below phone number when VoIP incoming call screen is displayed by the system, also, in native Phone app's call history. I have updated my answer with comments when these two functions will get called.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone's coming across this issue still, the problem for me was that I was unwittingly passing a null value for the `CXHandle` in `callUpdate` - and THEN that I was only checking for `nil` instead of `NSNull`.

**Old, buggy one:**

```
NSString *callerName = <nullable value from remote message>
CXHandle *callHandle = [[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:CXHandleTypeGeneric value:handle];

[provider reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:uuid update:callUpdate completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
...
}]
```

**New, working one**

```objectivec
NSString *callerName = <nullable value from remote message>
CXHandle *callHandle = [[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:CXHandleTypeGeneric value:handle];

if (callerName == (id)[NSNull null] || callerName.length == 0) {
    callerName = @"Faceless Man";
}

[provider reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:uuid update:callUpdate completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
...
}]
```

Comment: It's a little confusing to read your answer, mainly because your second line is referring to "handle" when this should be a "string", also the "handle" has not been defined anywhere in your code to test, would appreciate if you could please clarify this, thanks